# CSS styles applying differently when minified for stepper wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two  plunkers of material design wizard selector.One is having minified version of css and the other expanded.
Both are acting differently upon stepper clicks.
I wonder the minified file is not taking the transition effects of `.step-wizard .progressbar` class.

Please suggest what could be the reason for this change even though the code is similar.One minified and the other expanded.

```
-webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
```

Minified CSS plunker:

[Minified css-stepper wizard](https://plnkr.co/edit/IU4qmWAmSm50LEjOvsWU?p=preview)

Expanded CSS plunker

[Expanded css-stepper wizard](https://plnkr.co/edit/JTgvPyI4cJcnEuQljeiy?p=preview)

Comment: For me it works the same with minified or extended. The transition is working with both

Comment: Please find the updated links in plunker where you can check the difference.I minified my css using http://csscompressor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing `border: 1px solid e5e6e6;` from `.step-wizard .progressbar-stepper` class

Link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cXCip2peth2EHtZiTnUK?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

the stepper clicks work fine on both versions, only difference I see the border under .progressbar are different.

expanded has:

```
border: 1px solid e5e6e6;
```

minified has:

```
border:1px solid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your typo.
Your color code is wrong.

Your color code is

```
.progressbar {
position: absolute;
background-color: #0aa89e;
opacity: 0.4;
height: 12px;
border: 1px solid e5e6e6; // have a look here. color code has no #
```

}

You need to change like this

```
.progressbar {
position: absolute;
background-color: #0aa89e;
opacity: 0.4;
height: 12px;
border: 1px solid #e5e6e6; // you need to change color code
```

}

Comment: @forgottofly I saw it, you still got a typo. you need to edit color code. color can't express without # code. So please change your color code in style.css file like this (e5e6e6 -> #e5e6e6)